# Java - Multiple accepted inputs"

Tags: java, if-statement, operators, logical-or

I was just curious how you would accept multiple inputs in Java, from what I have tried you're unable to use the logical OR operators `||`.

So if I wish to have multiple accepted inputs accepted for an IF statement how would I do this?
`if (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("House" || "Home"))`
How can I have both House and Home activate this without creating an else statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if((userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("House")) || (userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("Home")))
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought i was on the right track I guess I just wasn't approaching it the right way. Can I use this multiple times (indefinitely?) to add all sorts of different combinations 
eg. for this I could use House, Home, Casa, Haus, Dwelling, etc?

Comment: Use Switch case if there are many inputs and if all the inputs are to be treated similarly, then use falling case statements (in this you don't add break statement after every case)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match against many predefined values, you could create a list of allowed values (in fixed case) beforehand and then simply use `List.contains()` for asserting the correct input:

```
final List<String> validValues = Arrays.asList("HOUSE", "HOME", "CASA");

if (validValues.contains(userInput.toUpperCase())) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: As @vikasn91 said using a Switch case would be good, do you believe this is better than using a switch case?

Comment: Yes. A `switch-case` is useful for replacing an `if` clause with multiple `else if`s but will be not very readable when you need to replace a single `if` clause. You can try both alternatives and see which one feels better.